# lucene index special characters

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, special-characters

I am indexing fields with characters like <,{,//," etc in Lucene 
Is that fine?

My search query will not contain these special characters but the fields which will be retrieved in response to query might contain one or more of these.

Table: keywords
Fields->keyword,text

When the user will enter a search term, it will be matched against the column keyword which will have special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it doesnt matter as long as your search term/search phrase/search query doesn't contain special characters